# Index not found exception when taking snapshot

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried to take a snapshot on just one index with below like request:

```
PUT /_snapshhot/esbackup/snapshot_myindex_20211101
{
  "indices": "myindex",
  "ignore_unavailable": true,
  "include_global_state": false
}
```

But got below odd error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [{
        "type": "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason": "no such index [_snapshhot] and [action.auto_create_index] ([.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history-*]) doesn't match",
        "index_uuid": "_na_",
        "index": "_snapshhot"
      }
    ],
    "type": "index_not_found_exception",
    "reason": "no such index [_snapshhot] and [action.auto_create_index] ([.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history-*]) doesn't match",
    "index_uuid": "_na_",
    "index": "_snapshhot"
  },
  "status": 404
}
```

I am guessing it might be due to below elasticsearch.yml settings in my cluster:

```
action.auto_create_index: ".watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history-*"
```

But on idea how they are related.

Anyone knows the reason and how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that the reason of exception - error in the API:

```
PUT /_snapshhot/esbackup/snapshot_myindex_20211101
```

In the _snapshhot you have double h

Comment: thanks. I just found the typo :) the error message is confusing though.

Comment: because you didn't hit the `_snapshot` API, Elasticsearch thinks you wanted to create an index, which is why you got that response